# What is meant by "dead past"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, literature

The poem "Opportunity" by Walter Malone has a line

> My judgments seal the dead past with its dead.

I could not find the real meaning of the "dead past" in the Oxford dictionary. Anyone help me please.

Comment: It's poetry. You're supposed to find your own meaning in the text. If you understand preceding references to ***splendours that have sped*** and ***vanished joys***, it shouldn't be too hard. If you ***don't*** understand those references either, you probably shouldn't be trying to read relatively antiquated poetry in a foreign language in the first place.

Comment: Does it mean wasted  early life or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

The line "My judgments seal the dead past with its dead," is a direct reference to Matthew 6:21-22 from the Bible, book of Matthew.

https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%208%3A21%2D23&version=ESV

> 21 Another of the disciples said to him, “Lord, let me first go and bury my father.”
> 22 And Jesus said to him, “Follow me, and leave the dead to bury their own dead.”

The speaker is meant to be a Christ figure or Jesus himself.

What it means, first, is that the past is over. is not the present; it is unliving, not active, of no effect. Thus, it is *dead*.

To *seal* something, means to put it in a container with a seal, so that you are prevented from getting into it.

The speaker's judgments *seal the dead past with its dead* means that the speaker's judgments have placed the past and everything that came from what has already happened (hurts, fears, consequences) -- where the audience cannot access it.